# java regex to replace only alphanumeric word in a url

Tags: java, regex

I am new tor regex trying to replace combination of alphanumeric word only in a url with a a value XYZ. Somehow its failing. I tried something like this

```
replaceAll("(\\.*/)([a-z0-9])([\\/])", "$1$3");
```

Please help me to suggest me regex.

1. It should ignore the hostname and port
2. replace only combinationation of alphanum

input: `https://somehost:someport/employee/v1/salaries/123/as56hgXWF`

expected output: `/employee/XYZ/salaries/123/XYZ`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String str1 = "https://somehost:someport/employee/v1/salaries/123/as56hgXWF";
    //String str2 = "/employee/v1/salaries/123/as56hgXWF";
    String str2 = str1.replaceAll("^http.*://[a-zA-Z0-9.:]+", "");
    String rgx = "(?<=([a-zA-Z0-9][/\\\\]))((([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]*))|(([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)))";
    System.out.println(str1.replaceAll(rgx, "XYZ")); // print ->    https://somehost:someport/employee/XYZ/salaries/123/XYZ
    System.out.println(str2.replaceAll(rgx, "XYZ")); // print ->    /employee/XYZ/salaries/123/XYZ

}
```

Hope help you! :)

Comment: Thank you so much it worked like charm. Appreciate your quick help.